# Adding dynamic content in rendered bootstrap popover template

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Actually I am facing problem while adding dynamic content with rendered template.

Popover Call:

```
$(selectorId).popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        title: 'New Post',
        html: 'true',
        content: _template,
        container: 'body',
});
```

Rendered HTML template

```
<div>
     <label>Name</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
     <label>Message</label><input type="text" name="message" id="messgae" />
     <label>Select Article</label><select name="article" id="article"></select> 
     <input type="button" value="submit">
</div>
```

Just need to focus on "Article". The select box is Empty in template and after rendering I am trying to append article data but its not working.

Appending data from db to select box

```
$.each(articles,function(){
   $("#article").append(this.articleName);
});
```

Article is a JSON array

```
[
  {
       'id': 1,
       'articleName': 'article1'

  },
  {
       'id': 2,
       'articleName': 'article2'

  },
  {
       'id': ,
       'articleName': 'article3'

  }
]
```

Problem: Select box is showing empty.

Goal: Whenever popover is opened user can able to select article from select box.

Comment: Does your code work for populating the select box if its outside of the popover? When are you calling the populate code? We can help better if you provide more complete code than snippets without context.

Comment: can u create a fiddle demo of it so that problem could be more understandable?

Comment: what is stored in 'articles' variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending article names to select box, while you should append options there as html

So it should be something like this:

```
$.each(articles,function(){
   $("#article").append("<option value='"+this.articleName+"'>"+this.articleName+"</option>");
});
```

**Update:**

Another problem could be that you are trying to append options to select box while it doesn't exist yet on page.
So, if you are appending template as a string (via 'content' property), you can initially compose tem plate with necessary select options:

```
var _template = "<select>";
$.each(articles,function(){
     _template +="<option value='"+this.articleName+"'>"+this.articleName+"</option>";
};
_template+= "</select>";
```

or you can also use 'container' property and pass

Comment: oh.. thanks.. but it still not appending, I think the problem is that it is not able to append data in already rendered template.

Comment: if you are using `$("#article")`, this element should be already present on page, while popover appends its content from new, when opening it, please have a look at my update in the answer